# Debug netlify lambda functions

Tags: javascript, webpack, netlify, source-maps

I have a website running in netlify and I also use netlify lambda functions.
I use vs code to debug lambda function locally by adding breakpoints to the build output and this works fine.

The problem is that sometimes it is hard to read bundled code and also when using loggers on prod the error details also give you which line has the error on the bundled code.

Does anyone know a way to add sourcemaps to the lambda build webpack configuration in order to be able to debug and to log sounrce code rather than bundled code?