# Debug Netlify Functions in VS Code

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, node-inspector, netlify-function

I'm trying to set a breakpoint inside of a netlify function that is executed via `netlify dev` with the following setup:

### Setup

#### Install [Netlify-CLI](https://www.npmjs.com/package/netlify-cli)

```sh
npm install netlify-cli -g
```

#### `netlify.toml`

```
[build]
  functions = "functions/"
```

#### `functions/hello.js`

```js
exports.handler = async(event, context) => {
    let output = `Hello, ${event.queryStringParameters.name}`
    return { statusCode: 200, body: output};
}
```

Here's a [sample project](https://github.com/KyleMit/netlify-func-debug) with the setup

#### Run

You should be able to run normally via `netlify dev`

[image: netlify dev screenshot]

Which will expose the function at the following address:

```
http://localhost:8888/.netlify/functions/hello?name=Kyle
```

### Debugging Attempts

#### `Launch.config`

In VSCode, you should be able to setup debugging with a `launch.config`.  I've tried the following configuration

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "type": "node",
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Program",
      "skipFiles": [
        "<node_internals>/**"
      ],
      "program": "${workspaceFolder}\\node_modules\\.bin\\netlify",
      "args": ["dev"]
    }
  ]
}
```

But I get the following error:

```sh
C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe .\node_modules\.bin\netlify dev
Uncaught c:\Users\kylemit\Documents\code\netlify-func\node_modules\.bin\netlify:2
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")
          ^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
<node_internals>/internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991
Process exited with code 1
```

#### Node `--inspect`

There are lots of examples that leverage the [`--inspect` switch`](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/) for node, but I can't figure out how to get that to work with VS Code Breakpoints.

#### Other Threads

- [Any way to debug functions? #409](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/409)
- [Netlify Dev functions - debugging and other issues](https://community.netlify.com/t/netlify-dev-functions-debugging-and-other-issues/4429)
- [Running netlify functions in a debugger](https://community.netlify.com/t/running-netlify-functions-in-a-debugger/9758/3)
- [Debug lambda functions locally #71](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/71)
- [Debugging help / using `--inspect` flag throws "error : unknown option" #148](https://github.com/netlify/netlify-lambda/issues/148)
- [Debug netlify lambda functions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63703439/1366033)

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I used to able to use breakpoints when I used netify-lambda but now that I switched to using esbuild, I can't. I switched to the launch.json config on their site https://cli.netlify.com/vscode/ and now it doesn't even run. I get the same error as you.

Comment: @SRCP, dredged up an answer and got it to work! Thanks for the nudge :) I'll delete this comment in 24 hrs

Answer (score 1):

From Tyson Matanich on [any way to debug functions?](https://github.com/netlify/cli/issues/409#issuecomment-715512172), you can do the following:

##### package.json

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "debug": "netlify dev --inspect",
  }
}
```

##### launch.json

```json
{
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Launch Node",
      "type": "pwa-node",
      "request": "launch",
      "runtimeArgs": ["run-script", "debug"],
      "runtimeExecutable": "npm",
      "skipFiles": ["<node_internals>/**"]
    }
  ]
}
```

[image: Example Screenshot]

Comment: Error: unknown option '--inspect'

Comment: You might be able to try `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect netlify dev`

Comment: If I run it with F5 in a function file, I get `/opt/homebrew/bin/npm run-script debug
> debug
> NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect netlify dev; Process exited with code 1` in VScode debug terminal.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I debug Netlify functions. (Sorry, not VSCode but I find this easier than VSCode launch.json configs.)

1. Install netlify-cli global: `npm install -g netlify-cli` re: https://cli.netlify.com/functions-dev/#debugging-functions and run command line:

> On Windows `cmd /V /C "set NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect && netlify functions:serve"`
> or on Mac\linux: `NODE_OPTIONS=--inspect netlify functions:serve`

You'll see `Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/` and a list of your functions: `◈ Loaded function yourfunctionname`

2. Open any Chrome DevTools window and look for the green node logo to show up in the upper left and click it. A new DevTools window will open with title "DevTools - Node.js".
3. Invoke your netlify function once (load the appropriate url in your browser i.e. `http://localhost:9999/.netlify/functions/yourfunctionname`)
4. Back in Chrome DevTools, click the Sources tab and see it open on the left, click the Node tab there and see your source file under the file:// hierarchy.
5. Create a breakpoint in Chrome Devtools and invoke your netlify function again and you should see the breakpoint hit.

My current configuration shown via command line `netlify -v` :
netlify-cli/16.3.1 win32-x64 node-v18.17.1